# Violence incidents or violent incidents?

Tags: orthography, academia

In an academic paper I discuss violent situations. Is it correct to refer to this as '*violence incidents*'? Or should I refer to it as '*violent incidents*' instead?

Comment: ...or even "incidents of violence"?

Comment: As you say, you discuss "violent situations," not violence situations.

Comment: They mean different things.

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct and used, but if you check our good friend [Gngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=violence%20incidents%2C%20violent%20incidents&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cviolence%20incidents%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cviolent%20incidents%3B%2Cc0), you'll find out that written texts give definite preference to ***violent incidents***.

As for ***violence incidents***, it is more likely to be used if *violence* is preceded by another modifier. See this article with the title

> Victims' perceptions of police response to ***domestic violence incidents***

from the [Journal of Criminal Justice](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0047235207000803)

On a [medical oriented site](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5006066/) I found this sentence:

> This study examined differences between self-report and actual documentation of ***workplace violence (WPV) incidents*** in a cohort of health care workers.

I tried hard (but not "to the end") to find instances of "violence incidents" on its own, and had no success. So ***violent incidents*** or ***incidents of violence*** are the best options.

Answer (score 2):

In broad terms,

1. The construction **an [adjective] [noun]** means **[a noun]** that is **[adjective]**.

Hence, if we use a real adjective and a real noun: **violent incident**, an **incident** that is **violent** / an **incident** whose state is **violent**.

2. The construction **A [noun1] [noun2]** means a **[noun2]** that is associated in some way with **[noun1]**. Hence, if we use real nouns: A **violence incident** = an **incident** that is associated in some way with **violence**.

**Adjective + noun** is very common.

**Noun1 noun2** is usually considered a compound noun and is often used as a term/name for a particular type of noun2. For example: Information Technology/The Language Department/dog collar, etc.

Comment: I think you probably have this right, but as written it is a bit confusing. Could you please edit to clarify what you meant when you wrote under your point **⒈** above, specifically where to find this “noun that ‘is’ an adjective” in your discussion of *violent incident*? Do you just mean the two-word sequence of an attributive adjective modifying the noun immediately following that adjective? Your point **⒉** seems solid and clear; I’m just fuzzy on your point **⒈** before it. Thanks.

Comment: @tchrist - done. (The number of adjectives is  irrelevant as are any adverbs modifying the adjective. It is also irrelevant if the adjective is post positional. However, I did not think these worth addressing given the question did not ask about them.

Answer (score 1):

They have subtly different meanings. In many contexts, the difference is too subtle to make much real difference, so they can be treated as interchangeable, apart from the considerations of style, which, as has already been pointed out count against *violence incidents*. There are, however, some contexts in which the choice is dictated by the meaning.

Suppose that one is discussing the incidents of X. In the context of that discussion, one notes that out of all observed incidents of X, say, 20% have been violent. In that case, one will want to refer to them as the violent incidents of X, and definitely not as the violence incidents of X. In other words, in the contexts in which there is an (explicit or implied) contrast with the nonviolent incidents of the same general kind, one needs *violent incidents*.

Answer (score 0):

'Violence incidents' seems incorrect to me, it reads oddly as they're both nouns. I would use 'Violent incidents' since the incident is the noun and the violent is the adjective. 'Incidents of violence' also works as suggested in comments.